# What is the C-language command for opening a connection with a foreign host over the internet

Tags: c

Could not find a direct answer to this anywhere. Can someone shed some lights. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such command built into the language. Sockets need to be used but they are platform dependent.

Comment: I was thinking something like that also. I guess the answer from Delan is for Linux.

Comment: Yes, on Windows it's `winsock.h`.

Answer (score 6):

There's no single C "command" (rather, function) to "open" a connection to a remote host.

First, you need a socket, this is provided by the `socket()` function (see your documentation for relevant header files). Then, you need to call `connect()` to establish the connection. However, that requires that all host names have been resolved, so you may have had to call `gethostbyname()` or similar, to turn a hostname into an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

Answer (score 1):

On [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741394%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), that would be `connect()`, but socket needs to be created first.